# Type string argument as interface function in go?

Tags: go

When you call NewSocialSeucirtyNumber function, I really don't understand how type socialSecurityNumber which has string type turns into Identifiable which has function of ID...

I know that return type is Identifiable, but how does socialSecurityNumber which is string type turn into argument for ID() ??
Can someone explain to me ?

```
type Identifiable interface {
    ID() string
}

type socialSecurityNumber string

func NewSocialSecurityNumber(value string) Identifiable {
    return socialSecurityNumber(value)
}

func (ssn socialSecurityNumber) ID() string {
    return string(ssn)
}
```

Comment: `socialSecurityNumber` and `SocialSecurityNumber` are 2 different types. One is not even shown in your code. Very confusing. Where is `ID` taking an argument??

Comment: actually that's an typo.. it is both lowercase with s

Comment: the return type `Identifiable` points to a concrete type `socialSecurityNumber` and `ID()` is a method receiver for `socialSecurityNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you got `socialSecurityNumber` started with lowercase `s`. It should match the `SocialSecurityNumber` receive parameter type in implementer function of the `Identifiable.

```
func (ssn SocialSecurityNumber) ID() string {
    return string(ssn)
}
```

Type is recommended to be started with uppercase.